# Mixing shared_ptr and a normal ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have a `shared_ptr` pointing to a buffer of dynamically allocated memory of `char`s. Let me call that `shared_ptr` `OwnerSharedPointer`.

Now if I declare:

```
char * borrowerPtr;
```

and do this:

```
borrowerPtr = OwnerSharedPointer.get();
```

and pass the `borrowerPtr` to some function which eventually uses the data stored in the allocated memory. Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: Not as long as you *know* the `shared_ptr` will outlive the raw ptr. Sometimes you need to do this, say to call a legacy C function.

Comment: How did you create “a `std::shared_ptr` pointing to a buffer of dynamically allocated memory of `char`s”? Such a thing does not exist. Only `std::unique_ptr` is partially specialized for arrays.

Comment: @5gon12eder It is sort of irrelevant. But yes, what I meant was each memory unit has the same size as that of a character.

Comment: If all the function does is use the pointer (it doesn't `delete` it and it doesn't store it for later or hand it to something else that does) it's good.

Comment: @TheBlueNotebook I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say in your last comment. What I wanted to point out is that `std::shared_ptr<char> sp = new char[42];` is not okay, even if it might compile cleanly.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Oh no. I am doing this:
sp = std::make_shared<unsigned char>(data_size);

Comment: @TheBlueNotebook That allocates a single `unsigned char` with the value `data_size`, not a buffer of size `data_size`.

Comment: Are you sure `std::shared_ptr` is what you need here? Do you have shared ownership? If not, you might be better off with a simple `std::vector`.

Comment: @TartanLlama I do have a shared ownership of resources. Also, working in a multi-threaded application and do need the shared_ptr.

Comment: @TartanLlama Also, didn't realise that bug. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @TheBlueNotebook Okay. To have a buffer owned by the `std::shared_ptr` you could use `sp = std::make_shared<std::vector<char>>(data_size);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything wrong with this?

Possibly. I can think of two scenarios:

1. The function calls `delete` on the pointer.
2. The reference count of the shared pointer goes to 0, and the pointee gets deleted before `borrowerPtr` gets used.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

If `borrowerPtr` is only used during the lifetime of `OwnerSharedPointer`, this is fine. The pointee will still be alive and well.

If `OwnerSharedPointer` is destroyed before you access `borrowerPtr` and it there is no other `std::shared_ptr` reference to the pointee, you'll be thrust into the dark realm of undefined behaviour. Don't do this.

If you don't know if `OwnerSharedPointer` will be destroyed before you access `borrowerPtr`, use a `std::weak_ptr` instead. This provides checked access to the pointee without increasing the owner count.